# Azure Pipeline Parallelism option

Tags: azure, pipeline

I am new to azure pipelines, started learning & in the process of creating my very 1st yaml pipeline.

My project is private, I am using a multi-stage templated pipeline, self-hosted as need to concurrently deploy a java web application to 7 VMs using mvn tomcat7 plugin run: command
so as to run selenium automation tests in parallel across all the VMs. A template pipeline which is called 7 times to deploy to all the VMs is such that it needs to stay running as
necessitated by the embedded tomcat instance on each of the VMs which in turn requires the ability to have parallelism.

Is it possible to have several parallel jobs running without turning my project from a private one to public ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Public project

Up to 10 free Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs that can run for up to 360 minutes (6 hours) each time No overall time limit per month

#### Private project

One free job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per mont. You can pay extra to get parallel jobs.

#### Self Hosted Agent

You can just setup your own self hosted agents, it just a script you run on a VM, takes about 10min per agent plus of course you need to install the software you need on the agent(s) and then you don't have those restrictions.